# put title for NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, navigationbar

I have the following:

**header file**:

```
 UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
  UINavigationItem *navigationItem;
```

**implementation file**:
in `viewDidLoad` method I tried these:

```
self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"title text";
```

and also this:

```
  self.navigationItem.title = @"MyTitle";
  [self.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
```

But no title seems to appear on the black up bar:

[image]

Has anyone any idea?Thank you!
**EDIT**:
[image]

Comment: Who does create navigation bar? How do you out that view?

Comment: try in viewDidLoad please add  self.title=@"Title";

Comment: Why don't you just set the title in Interface Builder?

Comment: I have my reasons.Title will change each time I load this..:)

Comment: any reason why you are hiding viewController's default navigationitem? with your own UINavigationItem *navigationItem;

Comment: Don't get you!PLease explain........No reason:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should define in your class property:

   `@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;`
2. You should set that class as `File's Owner`.
3. You should connect your navigation bar with property from *1.* (Using IBOutlet)
4. Now you can set its title using : `self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"title text";`

Comment: No working.There is a problem...even if I set the title by xib file...I can't see it on the simulator!

Comment: Your IBOutlet `view` of controller is connected to what view in xib?

Comment: working 100%
if you stuck that mean you created xib file copying other file. Check all connection references, if you see any exclamation sign (!), that means something went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
label.text = [dataItem objectForKey:@"title"];
[label release];
```